# Why is my new element wrapped in an array?

Tags: jquery

Why is my new element wrapped in an array?

```
$('<a>')
[<a>​</a>​]
```

When I try to use it with `appendChild` I get a dom exception 8 error.

Edit: That was an example. My exact code is

```
addendum = $("<a>", {href: download_url, text:"Download .nupkg file"})
badge = $(".nuget-badge")[0]
badge.appendChild(addendum)
```

Comment: Can you show how using appendChild with that isn't working?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why don't you use its `.append()` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All jQuery objects are array-like objects. Selecting the first element in the collection with `[0]` will return just the one element. If you instead log the jQuery object, it will appear to be an array in the console.

Note, jQuery has a built-in method called .append that should do what you want.

```
$('<a>').append('<span>Hello World!</span>');
```

or

```
$('<a>').append(someotherelement);
```

or for your given code:

```
$(".nuget-badge").append($("<a>", {href: download_url, text:"Download .nupkg file"}))
```

or (preferred)

```
$("<a>", {href: download_url, text:"Download .nupkg file"}).appendTo(".nuget-badge");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append an element to `body` like this:

```
$('body').append($('<a>',{text:"test", href:"#"}));
```

So I don't see a real problem with the way you are creating the element

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
var addendum = $("<a>", {href: download_url, text:"Download .nupkg file"});
$(".nuget-badge").append(addendum);
```